# How can I make "pre" scroll in chrome too?

Tags: css, overflow

`white-space:pre` scrolls by default in Firefox, how can I make it scroll in Chrome too? (and I do not care about IE.)

I've tried `overflow: auto;`, `overflow: scroll;` and `white-space: pre;`, but none of those worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might try `overflow:scroll`. Take a look at [the definition at HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/overflow/).

Comment: I edited my question to say that <code>overflow: scroll</code> doesn't work either

Comment: have you set `width` or `height` also?

Comment: @bluefoot - setting the width was the answer I was looking for.